# color picker for extjs

Tags: extjs

Are there any color picker for extjs (such as photo shop color picker) that developed only on extjs (not in jQuery).

I’m using (Ext.ux.ColorPicker) ux.colorpicker but, it can’t fill my requirement.

Thanks,
Thanuja.

Comment: If you're using extjs 4 you can check out this user extension: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205285-ExtJS-4-Color-Tools

Comment: There are some errors in these pickers in ext 4.1 above.

Answer (score 6):

ExtJS has a simple colorpicker.
xtype: '[colorpicker](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.picker.Color)'

From the help:

```
Ext.create('Ext.picker.Color', {
    value: '993300',  // initial selected color
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        select: function(picker, selColor) {
            alert(selColor);
        }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at [this one](https://github.com/sam-wheeler/Ext.ux.ColorPicker) which is more Photoshop-esque and works with Ext JS 4x+, but does require canvas support.

Comment: I [forked this](https://github.com/ryankane/Ext.ux.ColorPicker), made some modifications and it works well in ExtJS 6.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question. but nevertheless for people looking to have these two libraries play nice... here is what I did.  The problem lay in that jscolor expects all the inputs with class "color" to be available on window.load, which is called via jscolor.install().  Of course, ExtJs elements are not available at that time. Try this:

```
Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text",{
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    fieldCls:"color",
    name:"TestPost",
    listeners: {
        afterrender: {
            delay:200,
            fn:function(item){
                jscolor.init();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Running jscolor.init() will start it all up.  If you like, you can comment out the jscolor.install() call at the bottom of the jscolor.js file, so long as you call jscolor.init() as a listener that runs after the rendering of the textfield you want to be your color picker.